# Varchar used inside in clause fails

Tags: mysql

I have a stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `spSetExtracted`(IN `reportDataIdList` VARCHAR(1124))
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN
    UPDATE
        reportdata
    SET
        Extracted=1
    WHERE
        ReportDataId in ( reportDataIdList )
    ;
END
```

That is failing with this error:

```
Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '1387182,1387162,1387287,1387427,1387212,1387252,1387257'
```

As you can see, the list of ids above is a varchar coming in, and I am expecting to set the extracted flag for each of those ids.

Is there something further I need to do with the reportDataIdList?

Here is the table definition:
CREATE TABLE `reportdata` (
    `ReportDataId` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `ReportFieldId` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `CompanyId` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `DataDate` DATE NOT NULL,
    `ReportDataItem` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `Extracted` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`ReportDataId`),
    INDEX `FK_ReportData_ReportField` (`ReportFieldId`),
    INDEX `FK_ReportData_Symbol` (`CompanyId`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_ReportData_ReportField` FOREIGN KEY (`ReportFieldId`) REFERENCES `reportfield` (`ReportFieldId`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'

Comment: You are having quoted comma separated int values, I think you will need to pass comma seperated quoted int values like '1387182','1387162','1387287',...''

Comment: No joy, I get the same error.  I have found examples where the 's are not required for integral fields.

Comment: The select will work with the quotes around comma seperated values but not the update.  Try for your self and see.

Comment: Actually either way works when I run commands in the sql client directly, so that is not the issue.  I thought it may have to do with the size of the input varchar, so I have decreased it to 124 and am passing in only a couple of ids and that fails.  So I think it must have something to do with getting the information into the in clause from the input string (Varchar).

Comment: The update with update reportdata set extracted=1  where reportdataid in ('1387182,1387162,1387287,1387427,1387212,1387252,1387257');  will give the error.  The update won't work with that.

Comment: That is the error message.
The string going in is 1387182,1387162,1387287,1387427,1387212,1387252,1387257

Comment: There is no inbuilt mysql function to convert a string to a list of strings so you will either need to pass one by one or you will have to rewrite the procedure to split the string into seperate ids and then itereate over it and update.

Comment: CALL `spSetExtracted`('1,2,3') is how is is called from the command line, and that works.  It must be something about the C# connector I am using.

Comment: Two things, first the CALL is also showing the same error, second as I was looking at your procedure I am wondering why you need a procedure for a single update statement.  Unless this is a start for a bigger procedure which does other things also, you should be able to execute the update statement without the procedure with proper IN clause.